# Are the eigenvalues of the Laplacian of a generic Kähler metric simple?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

It is a [theorem of Uhlenbeck](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2374041) that for a generic Riemannian metric, the Laplacian acting on functions has simple eigenvalues, i.e., all the eigenspaces are 1-dimensional. (Here "generic" means the set of such metrics is the complement of a [meagre set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set) in the space of all metrics on a given manifold.)

I would like to know whether this property is also true for a generic Kähler metric. More precisely, given a compact complex manifold with a fixed choice of Kähler class, is it true that for the generic representative of this class, the Laplacian acting on functions has simple eigenvalues?

(To be honest, on a first reading it seems as if one might be able to apply similar arguments to those of Uhlenbeck to prove this result. I guess I would like to know if someone has already done this, or if there is a cunning counter-example that I'm missing, before I commit the time and energy to try!)